# Как выглядит содержание SYN/ACK пакета?

Tags: tcp

Как выглядит SYN/ACK пакет, а точнее его содержание

Comment: что ты имеешь в виду под «содержанием»? ни каких нaгрузочных данных в этом пакете нет... просто обычный tcp-пакет с установленными флагами SYN и ACK...

Comment: Возможно, имеется в виду, что хочется увидеть пакет, в котором установлены флаги и инкрементированы счетчики по сравнению с предыдущими пакетами. Но тогда проще запустить wireshark или tcpdump и посмотреть ими